# save image from webpage without requiring server to still have the image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I often load images in new tabs and sometimes leave them there overnight. Despite the image being fully loaded in its tab, when I go to save, chrome informs me there is "no file", which presumably means it is no longer found at that address on the server, and refuses to save. I assume the file has also fallen out of chrome's cache.

1. Is there reason chrome doesn't remember a tiny bit of metadata and regenerate the image from the view if it can't fetch it from the server or cache? Because it's kinda really frustrating to not be able to save something that's right there.
2. Starting from an unmodified page, without preparation, how could javascript (through an extension if needed) be used to save an image under these conditions?

Failing that, a somewhat annoying solution is to have an extension that saves the image temporarily on tab load, and then monitors downloads so it can serve the saved images when appropriate.

Comment: I don't see why chrome doesn't keep images on open pages cached until the page is closed. Though it wouldn't be the first time I've seen negligible improvements in resource usage justify decreased usability.

Comment: [canvas.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), [canvas.toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

Comment: Is `cache` disabled at `DevTools`? Are the images served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers?

Comment: @guest271314 Cache isn't disabled, and there's no access-control-allow-origin headers on the images. There is a `cache-control: public, max-age=1800` and an expiration header to match.

Comment: You should be able to get the images at `console` when visiting the page.

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks, I got it to work in console using what DanielHerr posted. An extension's content script should be able to do this too, right?

Comment: @Tet Have not tried the process at a content script, here. You could try what what was successful at `console` at content script.

Comment: This will work when done on the domain the image is from, but doesn't work if the image is embedded in another page, due to the canvas being "tainted" by off domain content.